# R msm package does not generate estimates

Tags: r, hidden-markov-model

I am trying to use the MSM R-package to estimate a continuous-time hidden Markov model. I do not know why my code does not show the estimates and confidence intervals for the transition intensities and the hidden Markov model parameters when I print the msm object.

I am attaching the data file and the code I am using. I am brand new to HMM. Any help are sincerely appreciated!

Data: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1qirk7fpCmFvQ6seI3iXKJl-M9ppd50vr/view?usp=sharing

````
library (tidyLPA)
library (dplyr)

three.q<-rbind(c(0.3,0.2,0.1),c(0.25,0.5,0.25),c(0.1,0.5,0.25))

hmodel1<-list(hmmNorm(mean = 0.5, sd=0.5),hmmNorm(mean = 20.8, sd=25.1),hmmNorm(mean = 304.9, sd=203.3))

msm<-msm(Y~Day, subject=ID,data=HMMDatav0,qmatrix=three.q,hmodel =hmodel1, 
         hcovariates = list (~X, ~X, ~X), method="CG", 
         fixedpars=TRUE, control=list(fnscale=4000))

msm

sojourn.msm(msm,ci="bootstrap",cl=0.95, B=1000)
```
````